# Videos playing in upper left corner in jwplayer in mozilla..?

Tags: jwplayer

I have integrated jwplayer in my website to play videos uploaded on website server. I have tested the functionality with some mp4 and mov videos recorded by mobile phone. In chrome and safari its working fine but in mozilla, video playing in upper left corner. I have searched alot but didn't got any clue why it happening. Please help..!!

Below is the initialization code :

```
$('video').each(function() {
                var videoTitle = this.id.split('_');
                jwplayer(this.id).setup({
                    file: this.src,
                    title: videoTitle[0],
                    width: '170',
                    height: '232',
                    aspectratio: '16:10',
                    autostart: 'false',
                    primary: 'flash'
                });
            });
```

Comment: Could you please give us your sample code

Comment: There is nothing special in code.. its as simple as initialization of jwplayer. Videos downloaded from websites are working perfectly fine, only mobile recorded videos showing this issue. Edited my post to add sample code.

Comment: There is some issue of jwplayer on mozilla for mp4 and mov file . Make sure you have html5 or flash installed for mozilla . for more details go throug [http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference)

Comment: yeah i've seen that and also tried with different video players but getting the same issue. @abhimanyu

Comment: Ok if you could upload the test videos on dropbox and gives me the link , i will test it with my jwplayer. also please mention the jwplayer version as well as os on which you are testing.

Comment: BTW, you get the downvotes because you've included the jquery and javascript tags on your question. That draws in a bunch of viewers who don't know anything about JW Player, so they don't understand the question, and then downvote it. You're right - it's annoying as hell.

Comment: Please provide a link to where you are running the player on your site.

Comment: @abhimanyu you can test with any mp4 or mov video recorded with cellphones.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer i can't give you the link as its implemented on user dashboard and admin panel. If you want to try it you can simple implement jwplayer as i did and upload a video from cellphone (recorded in the same cellphone).

Comment: Then yes, if it was uploaded from a portrait mode phone, it needs to be re-encoded.

Answer (score 2):

This is a familiar problem with videos recorded in portrait mode on devices like iPhones. Try running the video through Handbrake with its default options, plus check "Web optimized" (that just repositions the "moov atom" to enable streaming).

http://handbrake.fr/

Comment: Your suggestion is good but i need something like image magick which can be implemented in code and transform video in any manner or atleast we can rotate video frame.

Comment: If you need something server-side, you'll probably have to plunge into the mysteries of ffmpeg. I'm away from my development machine at the moment (the holidays, of course), but I'll post back when I get home. I think I can feed you the necessary ffmpeg attributes to fix this problem.

Comment: Try ffmpeg with this attribute (plus the ones for ID'ing the video, the output path, the codec, and so on): -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0